# Broken Laptop Screen - Display BIOS in External Monitor [Dell XPS l502x]

Tags: ubuntu, boot, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display

My laptop screen broke recently, so I connected an external display via HDMI. Though I can boot into Ubuntu, I still have to wait until the system boots to the login screen to see any output to the external monitor.

I'd like to view the boot screen and setup screen on the external display for installation of a new OS and other setups. I have tried the following options, but none works.

1. **Action:** Closed the lid as soon as I pressed the start button.

   **Result:** No display on external.
2. **Action:** Pressed <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> repeatedly during the boot.

   **Result:** No display on external.
3. **Action:** Pressed <kbd>F2</kbd> to get to `boot options`.

   **Result:** No display on external.
4. **Action:** Disconnected the laptop LCD completely.

   **Result:** Eight beeps (display error beeps). Not sure if the system is actually booting. I left it for five minutes to beep. No display whatsoever.
5. **Action:** Disconnected the LVDS display cable from the board.

   **Result:** Eight beeps (display error beeps). No display.

Additional info: The only way I can even type my password in Ubuntu screen is by keeping the lid open and wait until the monitor receives the HDMI signal. Later, I had to turn off the laptop display from `Display Settings`.

Comment: Try this on for size: [28799](http://superuser.com/questions/28799/broken-laptop-screen-boot-straight-to-external-monitor-in-vista). I know, it's not exactly the same, but it should work in this case.

Comment: @Dooley_labs - Action 2 :) I tried it multiple times. External monitor receives the HDMI signal only when it reaches the Ubuntu login screen.

Comment: hmm... that's odd. The external display should activate sooner than the login screen. That's the most you can do as far as my knowledge extends. Maybe someone else knows something.

Comment: Does the laptop have VGA? I'd try that if possible.

Comment: @Yanzzee. Nope.

Comment: @Ken Were you able to do it? Boot bios (not just windows, but since beginning / even before booting Windows) on external monitor connected with mini display port or hdmi port?? When press the start button and immediately close the lid, the external monitor does indeed shows Windows after some time of bootup. But I dont want to see Windows. I want to see stuff since beginning after I push start button, XPS logo, POST etc, for same reason that, if I want to format and reinstall clean Windows, it should be doable without LCD. Am afraid LCD will go bad sooner as it flickers, though very rarely.

Comment: @Mahesha999, no mate. It never worked. In your case, you can re-install Windows by connecting your hard disk on a diff machine. Then connect it back, boot into Windows and install the rest of the drivers.

Comment: argh, yess, that will work.., lolz I didnt guessed that. But its surprising that we cannot do that with L502X, as most other laptops does allow it. I found [this forum](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/l502x-modded-bioses-download-gpu-voltages-and-more.635536/) where people have uploaded modded BIOSes for L502X, though mostly for gaming purpose. I believe they must be able to do this. But I dont have enough reps to ask / comment on this forum. Anyways super thanks for suggesting a great point.